# React 18 App Displays Blank Page in Embedded Chromium You need to enable JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chromium, chromium-embedded

I'm still new to React and believe this may be some type of compatibility error.

My React 18 app uses a .NET 6 backend and renders pages fine on Chrome v112, Edge v111, and Firefox Developer Edition v113. However, when I render the page in an embedded Chromium app, it displays a blank page. If I inspect it, the message is "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." Unfortunately, I do not know the exact version of the embedded Chromium but believe it is at least 2 versions behind the main release.

However, if I open the default swagger page that the .NET 6 backend provides, via my-app.com/swagger/index.html, it displays the swagger page fine.

I believe the issue is with my react app but I do not know what the issue could be.

I have verified that it is likely not a proxy issue, at least on the mentioned browsers.

I do not believe it is because I need to enable Javascript because other websites load just fine like YouTube.

I am using the following packages that may be causing a problem:

- bootstrap 5.2.3
- http-proxy-middleware 2.0.6
- jotai 2.0.2
- react 18.2.0
- react-dom 18.2.0
- react-pdf 6.2.2
- react-router-dom 6.3.0
- react-router-bootstrap 0.26.1

I am not sure what else to check at this point so if you need any more info, please let me know. Thanks!